# Aggregate functions with custom data types

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I have a table containing the column

```
@Column(name = "duration", nullable = true)
@Convert(converter = DurationConverter.class)
protected Duration duration;
```

The converter is a simple

```
public class DurationConverter implements AttributeConverter<Duration, Long>
```

Is there any way to get the Criteria Api to allow me to use aggregate functions which would normally require a java.lang.Number?

So basically I want to use the converter anywhere in this call:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = ...;
cb.avg(root.get(MyClassName_.duration))
```

I know I could just use a Long as the field type and I will if I need to, but I hope I'm overlooking something here.

Comment: What happens when you execute the criteria query like in your example. Do you get an exception?

Comment: It won't compile because CriteriaBuilder::avg expects an Expression<N> with <N extends java.lang.Number>

Comment: root.get(MyClassName_.duration) returns an Expression<Duration>